# Amazon Corretto 11 is uninstalled with Installation of Corretto 15

Tags: java, java-11, corretto, java-15

I just downloaded [Amazon Corretto 15](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/corretto/latest/corretto-15-ug/windows-7-install.html) and installed it on my Windows 10 Laptop. Corretto 8 and Corretto 11 are already installed. However, after installing Corretto 15, Corretto 11 was uninstalled! Corretto 8 was still there. Has anyone had similar experiences? Is it not possible to install Corretto 11 and Corretto 15 in parallel?

I still need to be able to develop for Corretto 11 because most of our servers are running Corretto 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the option of setting a custom installation path. By default, Amazon Corretto 15 is installed at C:\Program Files\Amazon Corretto. If you set a custom path, make a note of it for the next step.

When installing Corretto 15, did you leave the default path?  You might have had Corretto 11 at that path, and so it overwrote it.

-------- Edited ------

If you have 11, then install 15, *you will see 11 removed*

If you have 15, then install 11, *you will see 15 removed*

JDK 8 will be left in either scenario.  I believe it is the new installers have been updated to remove versions that could potentially cause conflicts.  (11 vs 15)

If you want 11,set it up in a different path in the initial installation

Comment: Yes, I left the default path and I already had installed Corretto 11 at that path. I was surprised why Corretto 11 was uninstalled, as I did not have to change the default path when installing Corretto 8 and Corretto 11 to install both versions.